# Parallelism and prepositions in '...not only...but also..."

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions, prepositional-phrases

Which is correct and why? If follow parallelism rule, (2) should be correct but I have seen (1) being used. I need to use "...not only...but also..." structure.

(1) Tom has friends not only in America but also in Canada.
OR
(2) Tom has friends in not only America but also Canada.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! These changes should be posted in the question itself. You may accomplish this by clicking on the 'edit' button below the body of the question.

Comment: I'd say "Tom has friends in America and Canada".

Comment: Need to use "...not only...but also..."structure. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 1):

The [parallelism](http://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/grammar-lesson-parallelism.php) rule doesn't say that everything that satisfies the rule is correct and nice: it just says that everything that does **not** satisfy the rule is **wrong**.

You can divide a sentence up in lots of different ways so that each clause contains the same grammatical components:

> 1) Tom not only **has friends in America** but also **has friends in Canada**.
>
> 2) Tom has friends not only **in America** but also **in Canada**.
>
> 3) Tom has friends in not only **America** but **Canada**.

All of these satisfy the rule: not all of them are equally nice. For me, the second example sounds nicest so that's the one that I would use.

Comment: "(1) Tom not only has friends in America but also has friends in Canada." doesn't seem to satisfy the parallelism rule which is to put the common works before "not only".

Comment: Please update your question with a link to the parallelism rule that you are referring to. This sentence is not a problem according to the link that I provided.