# Wrong structure of Not only...but also?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

*Question courtesy KhanAcademy*
[image]
Question (on the right) is referring to part [11] of the paragraph (on the left). Question statement (not shown in picture) is to select best possible rewrite of the underlined portion of part 11, and make it grammatically correct. I marked NO CHANGE but correct answer given is C.

According to me, "not only...but also" construction should not have any punctuation at all, and if it does, should contain only a comma. Hence I marked A as my choice.

For example, in this question - [Parallelism and prepositions in '...not only...but also..."](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/91888/parallelism-and-prepositions-in-not-only-but-also) - we can see how the correct answer makes use of no punctuation at all.

However here they've indicated use of a semi-colon is correct. Can someone please explain why this is correct?

#### **UPDATE:**

**I had not been taught the "not only...also" construction in school**, hence, it was my natural subconscious decision to insert a "but" in the passage. I thus failed to notice that the "but" is in fact missing. However, the information in the below answer is still useful for people interested in the "not only...also" pattern.

Comment: You should discard this source of grammatical "information"--the authors erroneously label the independent *trailblazer* clause as a relative, and they do not acknowledge that use of the comma varies widely from writer to writer.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text.  They can't be searched, they're unfriendly to users who use screen readers or other assistive technology, and there's just no point to it.

Comment: @stangdon yes you're right. I usually try to avoid doing this. The problem though is **I can't copy the text from that KhanAcademy site** under Writing and Language tests. Now, even if I do write the text, if I only write the sentence I'm concerned about, then I might miss out on relevant contextual information in the preceding or succeeding sentence. Moreover the options on the right - as you can see - are replete with information which provides you with helpful info as to what was going on in the mind of that KA author when he marked option C as correct. That's the reason why I pasted image.

Comment: @stangdon Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you! :D

Comment: Person who voted to close  may please clarify what portion of my query is unclear. Thank you!

Comment: If you can't copy and paste, you can still type it all out longhand, or just use the image as a backup for the quote of just the relevant bits. Laziness is no excuse for using an image of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ELL answer you cite is about the "not only ... but also" pattern.  However, there is no **but** in the Walker text.

There is *usually* no punctuation when **but** is present, and there is *usually* some form of punctuation in a **not only** construction without **but**.

> She not only sings but acts.
>
> She not only sings, she acts.

As StoneyB mentions, few punctuation rules are rigid and universally accepted. These would be permissible as well:

> She not only sings, but acts.
>
> She not only sings she acts.
>
> She not only sings; she acts.
>
> She not only sings—she acts.

Comment: Sorry, I did fail to notice that the "but" was missing. Actually **I have not been taught the "not only...also" construction in school**, hence, it was my natural subconscious decision to insert a "but" there. Please pardon it. Thanks for your information anyway!

Comment: No pardon required. We're all learners of  one thing or another.

Answer (score -1):

The sentence in question does not contain "but also".  Without the conjunction "but" it is two complete sentences and must be either written as two sentences or joined with a semicolon.